# SQL Server ALTER COLUMN NOT NULL has no effect

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, alter-column

The designers of table `SOME_TABLE` did not define a primary key, and worse, they set one of the columns that could define the primary key as NULLable (the others are OK).

The data for `SOME_TABLE.PrinterPos` does not contain any `NULL` values.

I am writing an upgrade script to apply to ~50 databases.

The following code is failing:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.SOME_TABLE 
ALTER COLUMN PrinterPos smallint NOT NULL;

ALTER TABLE dbo.SOME_TABLE 
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_SOME_TABLE 
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (SOME_TABLE_ID ASC, Store_ID ASC, PrinterPos ASC)
       WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, 
             IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, 
             ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY];
```

I get the message

> Cannot define PRIMARY KEY constraint on nullable column in table 'SOME_TABLE'.

It looks line the first command is being totally ignored. Although there is no message to indicate this.

1. To put it in it's own batch, I have tried executing the first command using `sp_executesql` to no effect.
2. If I execute the first command in SQL Server Management Studio followed by the second then it executes OK.

I need to get this change fully automated. How can I get this to work via script?

Comment: Try adding a GO keyword between the two ALTER TABLE commands

Comment: What @Sparky said (he should have made this a formal answer)

Comment: Sorry I did not make it clear the script is really a stored procedure, so GO is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a GO keyword between the two ALTER TABLE commands